# Java arrays and loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

After learning some basics of C, I somehow cannot grasp the logic behind loops in Java. For example: why a for-loop in Java should set:

```
for(i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
```

instead of:

```
for(i=0; i<=array.size(); i++)
```

In the second case, setting <= mostly results in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Thanks  a lot for any explanation.

Comment: It gives IndexOutOfBoundsException becuase array indexes are 0 (zero) based, and going upto size will cause this exception. If you declare array of 5 elements, indexes are 0 to 4, and array.size gives you 5, which cause above mentioned exception

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's a complete answer. You should write that as an answer below (an remove the comment after it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array-size returns the amount of objects in the list. So for example in

```
int[] array = new int[]{ 10, 20, 30 };
```

we have three integers, so the `.length` returns `3`.

The indexes of the array are counting from 0 upwards though, so in the array I mentioned above:

- `array[0]` is 10;
- `array[1]` is 20;
- and `array[2]` is 30.

`array[3]` however, which happens when you use `<= length`, will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 4):

Java arrays are indexed 0 to `length - 1`. Hence, if you try to access the element at `length` index, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: not just java, even in c or c++, array index starts from 0.

Answer (score 4):

Java array indexes are zero-based, just like they are in C. If you loop from zero to size, inclusive, you are going to go one past the end of the array.

For example, think of an array of ten elements. If you set up a loop with `<=`, your index will go from zero, inclusive, to ten, inclusive - eleven values in all. However, your array has only ten elements, so there would be an exception.

**Note:** Using `!=` in place of `<` is not uncommon, too, especially when you iterate by `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this array example:

```
[12,25,1,24]
```

array is of size 4.

```
array[0] = 12
array[1] = 25
array[2] = 1
array[3] = 24
```

So your loop should be from 0 to 3 (your first proposal, your second proposal would be from 0 to 4)

**EDIT:** Alternitavely you can use the for each loop if you don't care about the index.

```
for(Object o : objectArray){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An array is zero based, so the the last one of e.g. 3 elements has index 2. `[0, 1, 2]`